# .Net 6 Minimal API Define Enum Parameter In Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, .net-6.0

Is there a way to describe an enum in Swagger using a minimal API like there is for a controller-based API?

I have a simple enum:

```
public enum GeometryType
{
    WKT,
    GeoJson
}
```

and an endpoint:

```
app.MapGet("/geometry", (GeometryType? geometryType) =>
{

};
```

But the parameter is defined as a string in my swagger page and therefore I'm not getting the nice dropdown with the available options like I would with a controller:

```
{
 "name": "geometryType",
  "in": "query",
  "schema": {
  "type": "string"
 }
}
```

I've tried explicitly mapping the type in my Swagger setup:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.MapType<GeometryType>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "integer", Format = "int32", Enum = Enum.GetNames(typeof(GeometryType)).Select(name => new OpenApiString(name)).Cast<IOpenApiAny>().ToList() });
});
```

But that type never shows up in my swagger.json page, which leads me to believe its got something to do with the way .Net is creating that endpoint.

Comment: Maybe see https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1269

Comment: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/

Comment: https://avarnon.medium.com/how-to-show-enums-as-strings-in-swashbuckle-aspnetcore-628d0cc271e6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need be sure if it works in normal web api. If not working, be sure add the `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]`  to the enum

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
   public enum GeometryType
   {
       WKT,
       GeoJson
   }
```

or globally add the `JsonStringEnumConverter` in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

Then, you must define `[FromQuery]` before the parameter:

```
app.MapGet("/geometry", ([FromQuery] GeometryType? geometryType) =>
{

});
```

The json would be:

```
"parameters": [
          {
            "name": "geometryType",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "enum": [
                "WKT",
                "GeoJson"
              ],
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! You have to explicitly add `[FromQuery]` before the parameter as you said. It's weird because it was already a query parameter. I was able to avoid using controllers completely by adding a global `JsonStringEnumConverter` as you also mentioned, just in a slightly different way. ```services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that Swagger (OpenAPI) properly recognizes the enum type and provides a dropdown with available options, you can use the **[JsonConverter]** attribute to specify a custom converter for the enum type.

Example:

```
// Define your enum
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum SampleEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
}

// Add the endpoint to your app
builder.MapGet("/sample", (SampleEnum sampleEnum) => $"Selected enum value: {sampleEnum}")
    .ToEndpoint();
```

In this code, the **[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]** attribute is applied to the SampleEnum enum. This should instruct Swagger to represent the enum as a string in the Swagger UI, allowing you to see a dropdown with available enum options when testing the API through the Swagger UI.